How to convert images of complex tables into simple tables?
I am converting the following images of complex tables into simple tables(with single row and columns) the size of the table will increase and it may lead to extra table creation but i don't mind.
I tried using various python libraries but no satisfactory results.
I am expecting simple tables that have single row and column structure. i want to store them as data 'frames that will make sense and i can further process table data.
table1
table2
table3

what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

how to ask a good question:
how to ask

Do you literally have images, or do you have PDF files?  It's quite difficult to parse this kind of data from images.

i initially had pdf with multiple tables but then i extracted individual tables from the pdf in image format.
